# PADS Logic: how do I select parts by attributes/properties?

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, schematics, mentor-pads

I don't know if this question fits this site. I will try to explain the detail, but my question is specific to a tool set; how to use the "Mentor graphics PADS Logic" schematics capture tool. So, don't bother if you have not used PADS Logic. It is nothing of technical challenge. I just got stuck with it, and I need help.

---

Question:
I am trying to replace multiple parts in the PADS Logic VX.2.3 schematics capture tool. Is there a good way to select multiple parts with specific attributes (eg. all the 0.1 μF 0603, 50 V)?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the part with the attributes you want to select. In the context menu click Select All Parts of This Type.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I know. "All parts of this type" includes some of the attributes, but not "all". Siemens/MG support did not find right solution. I had to touch the parts manually. If you anticipate partial change of some group of parts, make a different symbol (copy).... IIRC,, I used common symbol "cap"/"res" for every cap/res, 100s. ex. copy "0.1 μF 0603, 50 V" -> change attr to 36V -> then test how the selection works.