# Is the LM399 Temperature coefficient with the heater on or off?

Tags: voltage-reference, temperature-coefficient

The [LM399 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/199399fc.pdf) specifies a temperature coefficient "\$\Delta\$T/\$\Delta\$Temp".  The conditions state an ambient range but don't specify if that's with or without the heater on.

Which is it?

Comment: Where the Temperature Coefficient goes, I see dV/dT, but no dT/dT. Whatever it is, T is the temperature that the Zener sees, doesn't matter with or without the heat from internal or external heater. BTW, could you answer, please, [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/596678/how-to-select-all-the-capacitors-with-0-1uf-in-pads-logic-vx-2-3),  if you know it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the Note 3:
"These specifications apply for 30V applied to the temperature
stabilizer and –55°C ≤ TA ≤ 125°C for the LM199; and 0°C ≤ TA ≤ 70°C for
the LM399."

Means that the heater is ON and powered through 30V. If you use different heating power, precision might vary.

Comment: Ah! I totally missed that note 3 applied to the table on the previous page too!